# How to get the relative URI of where my website is running?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a menu where users can upload their avatars, and I want to save that file path on disc where that image is located.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ChangePicture(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    using (EFJugadorRepository jugadorRepository = new EFJugadorRepository())
    {
        var jugador = jugadorRepository.FindJugadorByEmail(User.Identity.Name);

        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {

            var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            string fileName = String.Format("{0}{1}", User.Identity.Name, extension);

            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Public/Avatars"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);

            using (EFFotografiaRepository fotografiaRepository = new EFFotografiaRepository())
            {
                var fotografia = fotografiaRepository.FindAllFotografias().SingleOrDefault(f => f.fotCodigo == jugador.jugCodigo);
                if (fotografia == null)
                {
                    fotografia = new taFotografia();
                    fotografiaRepository.CreateNewFotografia(fotografia);
                }

                fotografia.fotCodigo = (int)jugador.jugCodigo;
                fotografia.fotTipo = 0;


                //string relativeRootPath = Url.Content("~/Public/Avatars");
                string relativeRootPath = "http://localhost:23188/Public/Avatars";
                fotografia.fotUrl = String.Format("{0}/{1}", relativeRootPath, fileName);
                fotografiaRepository.SaveChanges();

                jugador.jugFoto = fotografia.fotCodigo;
                jugadorRepository.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        // redirect back to the index action to show the form once again
        return RedirectToAction("CropPicture");
    }
}
```

If you notice, I commented out a line:

```
string relativeRootPath = Url.Content("~/Public/Avatars");`
```

This didn't work, understandably; and I had to manually type in the URI "localhost".

Is there a way to fetch the root URI and use it to save the path? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string path1 = HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;
string realPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath(path1);
```